# Styling html material design forms in vuejs

Tags: html, material-design, vuejs2, vuetify.js

AM using Vuetify js

I would like my form field to have a bottom black border when its not active and still retain the default blue and red color when active and with error

SO i have

```
  <v-text-field
          name="input-2"
          label="Label Text"
          value="Input text"
          class="input-group"
        ></v-text-field>
```

THe above generates the following form

[image]

as you can see there is no border

What am looking forward to get is

[image]

THe second one has a bottom bnlack border.

How do i go about this.

Comment: why did you add `.input-group`? Without it it should display properly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you did not place `v-text-field` inside `<v-app>`.

From [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/layout/pre-defined):

> In order for your application to work properly, you must wrap it in a
>   `v-app` component. This component is required for determining grid
>   breakpoints for the layout. This can exist anywhere inside the body,
>   but **must be the parent of ALL Vuetify components**.

Either that or update Vue and Vuetify to latest versions.